# Google Maps with JQuery AJax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple page which makes two JQuery AJAX calls to get parameters and then it updates a google maps Lat and Lng,

For some reason after the two AJAX calls are made, the google map then seems to timeout and go Grey.

Anyone ever experienced this before or have any ideas as of why it would be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: A video, screenshot, code, or even better a link to recreate the issue (jsbin.com / jsfiddle) would help a great deal.

Comment: a agree with redsquare we need more than what your giving us to go on

Comment: I don't think your even getting to your update function are you get the alert messages ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var pclat;
    var pclng;  
    var pc = document.forms[0]["postcode"].value;


    $.get("get_latlong.php", { cp: pc, cord: "Lat" }, function(data){
        alert("Lat: " + data);
        pclat = data;

    });



    $.get("get_latlong.php", { cp: pc, cord: "Lng" }, function(data){
        alert("Long: " + data);
        pclng = data;
    });


    updateMap(pclat, pclng);


 }



function updateMap(pclat, pclng){


    var postcodeLL = new google.maps.LatLng(pclat, pclng);
    map.panTo(postcodeLL);
    marker.setPosition(postcodeLL);
    marker.setMap(map);
```

}

Comment: this should really be included in the question not as an answer.